# I get an error when I try to upload a file to GCP using the python script

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I am try to upload a file to my Google cloud storage bucket using the following python script to upload it. But I get the following error while doing so. How can I solve it?

```
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('key.json')

def upload_blob(bucket_name, blob_name, filename):
    """ 
       Upload a blob to the bucket. 
       filename: source file name
       blob_name: destination blob name
    """
    bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)
    blob.upload_from_filename(filename)

upload_blob("synersense_data","patient_data","schema.txt")
```

This is the error below:

```
google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('invalid_grant: Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp values and use a clock with skew to account for clock differences between systems.', '{\n  "error": "invalid_grant",\n  "error_description": "Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp values and use a clock with skew to account for clock differences between systems."\n}')
```

Comment: Check your system time. It might be off.

Comment: @rdas I corrected the date and time but still it is giving same result

Comment: Check your timezone and check if NTP is properly configured.